# extracting measurements from .catpart in CATIA V5

Tags: vba, catia

I have .CATPART and I have manually done measurements. I want to create macro using CAT VBA and extract measurements from .CATPART and export it to excel.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, measures stored in the part or product are not exposed to in the API.

Answer (score 0):

I never found a solution for this, but here is a code that allow to get the measurements from the user selection. you can't parse all measurements, but you can select them and parse the selection (this example works only on one measurement selected, you'll have to adapt if possible for many):

```
Set oSelection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
On Error Resume Next
sName = oSelection.Item2(1).Value.Name
On Error Goto 0
'selection should be named with "catiabase"
If InStr(LCase(sName), "catiabase") = 0 Then Exit Function
'Get Name
'PROBLEM: This search will empty the selection if no measurement is selected
oSelection.Search "Name=Length,sel"
'No Length, no measurement (here i need only 1 selection)
If oSelection.Count2 <> 1 Then Exit Function

'Get name of measurement
sName = oSelection.Item2(1).Value.Name 'not the same as previous!
```

[You can also find here a method to get distance value between two parts](http://www.coe.org/p/fo/et/thread=25972), but it requires to know the parts you want to get distances from

Answer (score 0):

Imagining the simplest situation:

```
Sub CATMain()

''Get ActiveDocument
Dim partDocument1 As PartDocument
Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument

''Get Part
Dim part1 As Part
Set part1 = partDocument1.Part

''Get list of parameter of part
Dim oParams As Parameters
Set oParams = part1.Parameters

Dim PatternFind As String
PatternFind = "Measure"

''MsgBox all values of the parameter that contains 'Measure'
For Each item In oParams
    If InStr(item.Name, PatternFind) <> 0 Then
        MsgBox (item.Name & " = " & item.value)
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

[View of tree view]

- Part1
- Measures

  - MeasureEdge.1

    - Length=10mm
  - MeasureEdge.2

    - Length=100mm

You should do the necessary modifications to export to Excel.