# How to open a CATPart in MATLAB with full editing priviliges as well as in full windowed mode?

Tags: matlab

so far I have been improving my MATLAB skills to a level, which lead to to my nearly desired script completion. However I am missing one final step in order to complete my tast.

I wanted to open a CATIA V5 R21 file with the .CATPart extension. I am well aware that the common "open" command only works for supported file extensions by MatLab. However once I open the desired .CATPart File index tab opens in the MatLab editor with the following code:

[image]

I do not ask anyone to read this code for me since its useless because of the wrong opening method. Hence I would like to ask anyone if there is an Application in the Matlab which can be downloaded and installed in order to read the desired file properly.
The image above shows cleary that the "file opening process" causes no errors or warnings. Which finally led me to this question if I just need the right "communication tool" between the file itself and matlab.

Comment: You opened a binary file and presented it as text file. Binary files contain all possible numeric values to encode the content. Text files use standardized encodings like [ASCII](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Standard_Code_for_Information_Interchange#ASCII-Tabelle) or [UTF-8](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8). E.g. in ASCII the values 0-31 are non-printable characters. Therefore you can see these strange symbols. You have to open the file as binary file and parse it.

Comment: It seems that CATpart files are not documented and there is no support to open and read these files. There are basic APIs for some languages but you can't get all the values. You can either reverse engineer (very difficult) the file or you can try some unsupported converters.

Comment: So there is not even a possibility to start a Servercommand (like in excel) in order to open the file? In addition you mentioned some unsupported converters. Can I assume that you have experienced a similar situation with different files? Do you happen to now a source for such a converter?

Comment: I have no experience with CATIA. I saw some converters but I don't know if they help you. You didn't describe why you want to open these files. I saw CATIA to PDF converters. PDF is still binary but at least it's an open file format. I also found CATIA API e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28669245/extracting-measurements-from-catpart-in-catia-v5

Comment: Ok I will investigate that

Comment: Ok I found a rather roundabout way to achieve this conversion thanks to your hint. I will try to simplify my solution and post it here in the comment section, if there is further need in the future for others